# List all category and all posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

how do can i list all category and all posts in wordpress, like the example below:

```
CATEGORY1
POSTS

CATEGORY2
POSTS

CATEGORY3
POSTS
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code :

```
  <?php // get all the categories from the database
$cats = get_categories();
// loop through the categries
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
// setup the cateogory ID
$cat_id= $cat->term_id;
// Make a header for the cateogry
echo “<h2>”.$cat->name.”</h2>”;
// create a custom wordpress query
query_posts(“cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100″);

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>

<a href=”<?php the_permalink();?>”><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php echo ‘<hr/>’; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif;
// done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>

<?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do is call new WP query 3 times with unlimited number of posts like this:

```
<?php
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&category=CATNUMBER');
    foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="eachPost">
    <div class="eachImage">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
    </div>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Change the CATNUMBER with the category ID and repeat it 3 times.  Hope this helps.